# How to programmatically select a folder to view in Outlook 2010?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-2010

I am programmatically creating a search folder via Search.Save method.  After I save the search (it creates a new folder in the Search Folders directory), I would like to set to focus on this newly created folder such that the view changes to this folder.

This is the code I have thus far....

```
searchFolders = inboxFolder.Store.GetSearchFolders();
foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in searchFolders)
{
    if (folder.Name == "Expiring Retention Policy Mail")
    {
        folder.ShowItemCount = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlShowItemCount.olShowTotalItemCount;
        //folder.SetCustomIcon(new Bitmap(32, 32));
        folder.Display();
    }
}
```

When I do folder.Display() it opens up an entirely new inspector window... I don't want this to happen, I simply want to select it (like via set focus?) and have it viewed in the same inspector window it exists in.  Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you...

Get access to your `Application` object (or from the main add-in class). And then

```
this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = folder;
```

i.e. you can use `CurrentFolder` of the `ActiveExplorer`

> Of course, **always make sure to properly release your COM objects** (the ones that need releasing) - and
>   you should never do it like I did here (for simplicity) - i.e. chaining properties like
>   that. Save each (property) into a variable, and release via
>   `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on your way out.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked exactly!  I did `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = folder;`

Comment: @NSGaga Your answer is clear. thanks for that. But how I determine the newly created folder using code? Please explain. Thanks again

Comment: @KushanRandima I'm guessing you have an object of the folder don't you ? it depends on how the folder is created, if you have no influence on it you'd have to iterate through folders and find by timestamp or something (I'm just guessing, I don't have any outlook stuff in my mind for a while now:))